# Add one generic parameter to printf

Tags: c, printf

I think it is a wrapper function to printf. For example:

```
my_printf("Hello world\n")
```

prints

```
[1] Hello world
```

or

```
[hh:mm:ss] Hello world
```

I know I see it in Linux kernel but not sure how to implement it in my own application.

In first example above, the number is incremented so the next call to my_printf will be 2.
e.g

```
my_printf("Hello universe\n");
```

prints

```
[2] Hello universe
```

User is never passing generic parameter but still it is printed.

Comment: `static variables` - Look that up

Comment: Hi @EdHeal , not about the variable value itself, but how to supply it into the printf.
printf() itself already receives multiple of parameters (ellipsis), how to insert additional one without user declares it.

Comment: Write `myprintf` using varags and a static variable

Comment: int printf( const char * fmt, ... );


In my_printf(), how to add additional info to printf inside printf?

Comment: See [Static Variables in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-variables-in-c/) and [Variable Length Argument in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-argument-c/). A macro implementation is also possible with a static or non-static variable.

Answer (score 9):

The trick with a static variable was already mentioned.

2nd part of the puzzle is to use things offered in [`stdarg.h`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_list).

The last part of puzzle is [`vprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) which can be used for the variable argument list.

A sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int my_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  static unsigned counter = 0;
  int len1 = printf("[%d] ", ++counter);
  if (len1 < 0) return len1;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  int len2 = vprintf(fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
  return len2 < 0 ? len2 : len1 + len2;
}


int main(void)
{
  my_printf("Hello world.\n");
  my_printf("%s", "Hello world, again.\n");
  for (int i = 2; i <= 4; ++i) my_printf("Hello %d. world.\n", i);
}
```

Output:

```
[1] Hello world.
[2] Hello world, again.
[3] Hello 2. world.
[4] Hello 3. world.
[5] Hello 4. world.
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03de68d38bf71594)</kbd>

---

If the counter should be an argument instead of a `static` variable, `my_printf()` could be adjusted resp.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int my_printf(unsigned counter, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  int len1 = printf("[%d] ", counter);
  if (len1 < 0) return len1;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  int len2 = vprintf(fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
  return len2 < 0 ? len2 : len1 + len2;
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned counter = 0;
  my_printf(++counter, "Hello world.\n");
  my_printf(++counter, "%s", "Hello world, again.\n");
  for (int i = 2; i <= 4; ++i) my_printf(++counter, "Hello %d. world.\n", i);
}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef8b237d2873dbe1)</kbd>

Incrementing `counter` in `my_printf()` wouldn't affect the variable passed as argument. (C is always passing arguments by value.) In that case, the `counter` had to be passed by pointer instead.

Comment: Great example @Scheff. First time I know there is vprintf()  and how does variable counter passed into it? How can the counter be inserted as first variable in the args, is it always like that?

Comment: @AsamPadeh How do you want to pass the counter as argument? Before or after `const char *fmt`?

Comment: Your first example is my aim. But I am not sure how can the counter become 1st argument in the list ?

Comment: I mean how [%d] from printf is passed to vprintf ?

Comment: @AsamPadeh `%d` isn't passed to `vprintf()`. There is an 2nd, prior `printf()` for the output of counter in `my_printf()`.

Comment: @AsamPadeh Otherwise, implementation would be super complicated (IMHO) if possible at all.

Comment: How come the string [%2d] i.e counter value number becomes part of the args ?
Who pass it to args?

Answer (score 2):

Here goes - I was bored

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define myprintf counter();printf
void counter()
{
    static int i = 0;

     printf("%d", i);
     i++;
}
int main()
{
    myprintf("Hello World %d %s", 5, "Tea");
    myprintf("Hello World %d %s", 8, "Coffee");

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

As suggested

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define myprintf(...) do { counter(); printf(__VA_ARGS__); } while (0)

void counter()
{
    static int i = 0;

     printf("%d", i);
     i++;
}
int main()
{
    myprintf("Hello World %d %s", 5, "Tea");
    myprintf("Hello World %d %s", 8, "Coffee");

    return 0;
}
```

And this compiles and works!

Comment: That's a nice trick as well but wouldn't work in e.g. `if (false) myprintf("Hello world.\n");`

Comment: Yes, i agree, it is nice trick Ed :-)
But looking for more compact solution. I am still trying with variable parameters.

Comment: A bit better would be, if you replace `;` by `,` to make it a sequence expression. But this would still have issues (e.g. when used as argument where `,` could be evaluated as argument separator...)

Comment: The `do { /* ... statements ... /* } while (0)` trick was invented for just this purpose :)

Comment: `#define myprintf(...) do { counter(); printf(__VA_ARGS__); } while (0)` *or similar, cannot check right now*

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using static variables.
This ain't a variable "that you supply to the function without user declares it".
It is a variable that will never be instantiated more than once.

Example:

```
int increment ()
{
    // this line will only be "executed" on first call to increment ()
    static int count = 0;

    count += 1;
    return count;
}
```

Each time you will call increment (), it will return the next integer.

Comment: HI @Angevil, yes i know static variable, and now I want to supply that value to my_printf() itself.

Comment: Well you can just call increment () to get the new value :)
A more complicated implementation could be made if you want to increase / decrease / reset for instance.
But for your use case where you just increments the amount of calls you made, this should be sufficient. 

You don't supply the value to printf, it's printf itself that calls the increment () function :)